# how to crop string using a pattern in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

1. I would like to capture the set of characters from a string that matches the pattern using nodejs

```
ex: const inputString = '     abc 1 2 3  white_rabbit_123_456_789.txt pqr ';
    const pattern = 'white_rabbit_*_*_*.txt'
    expected output is white_rabbit_123_456_789.txt
```

I am okay if the output is a string or an array.

2. Also, now lets say I have multiple instances of pattern in the inputString

```
ex: const inputString = '     abc 1 2 3  white_rabbit_123_456_789.txt pqr 
  white_rabbit_312_456_888.txt';
    const pattern = 'white_rabbit_*_*_*.txt'
    expected output is ['white_rabbit_123_456_789.txt','white_rabbit_312_456_888.txt']
```

Any suggestion would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) maybe?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
const inputString1 = '     abc 1 2 3  white_rabbit_123_456_789.txt pqr ';
const inputString2 = '     abc 1 2 3  white_rabbit_123_456_789.txt pqr white_rabbit_312_456_888.txt';

const _match = string => string.match(/white_rabbit_\d+_\d+_\d+.txt/g);

console.log(_match(inputString1));
console.log(_match(inputString2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) passing a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) argument:

```js
const inputString = `     abc 1 2 3  white_rabbit_123_456_789.txt pqr 
  white_rabbit_312_456_888.txt
  white_rabbit_199212223_8888888_13456787.txt
  white_rabbit_1_2_3.txt
  white_rabbit_444_555_666_777.txt
  white_rabbit_888_999.txt`
const matchArray = inputString.match(/white_rabbit(?:_\d+){3}.txt/g)
console.log(matchArray)
```

I created a literal RegExp object (*pattern* between two forward slashes, followed by a *global flag*), in whose pattern I used a *non-capturing group* for "an underscore and one-or-more digits" *repeated exactly 3 times*.